# Get URL address of Html.RouteLink result

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, url, asp.net-mvc-routing

the result of

```
@Html.RouteLink("link-name" , "route-name" , new 
{
  id = "8850" ,
  title = "sample-title" ,
  description = "sample-description"
}
)
```

is

```
<a href="/8850/sample-title/sample-description/">link-name</a>
```

is there any extension method which provide just `href` address ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the **"Url.Action"**:

Of UrlHelper Class:

```
Action(string actionName, string controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues);
```

For other overloads, check this:

**[UrlHelper.Action Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action.aspx)**

Eg.

```
<a href="@Url.Action(actionName, controllerName, routeValues)">link-name</a>
```

Comment: An alternative would be to use Url.RouteUrl if routes have been named and have pre-determined route values.